# Can mobile web apps run in the background? (iOS & Android)

Tags: javascript, iphone, android, ios

Can mobile web apps run in the background? I'm mostly interest in iOS & Android.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, they can't. On Android you could conceivably install a different browser, but it's not possible on the stock one. @jgillman points out the exception of audio in iOS but that's the only exception I'm aware of.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is a situation that changes almost daily, I'll post an updated answer.  This applies to the recent releases of these browsers but may change tomorrow!

My [music app](http://thedigitalage.org/hangthedj) is HTML5 and needs to run in the background.  The support for that varies depending on mobile browser.

- Safari on iOS: will continue to play one or two songs in the background
- Native browser on Android: will play one song then stops
- Firefox on Android: will stop when screen locks or browser loses focus or song ends
- Dolphin on Android: plays in background but eventually stops
- Opera on Android: Excellent background support!  Javascript continues to run and music continues to play even when screen is off or Opera is sent to the background.  Opera even puts a play/pause toggle into the notification page.  Yay.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465242) is a related SO question.

Answer (score 3):

iOS allows audio from a web app (Mobile Safari) to be played in the background. I don't know about other events though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run web app in the background. To enable most of the native features, you should develop native application.

Comment: But on iOS in general, even Apple's native apps don't run in the background.

Answer (score 1):

At the time of this answer, Firefox mobile and Opera mobile for Android do allow javascript to run in the background, even with the screen locked.