# HTML5 website running while phone screen is off?

Tags: html, mobile, geolocation, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Basically, my question is the same than [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465242/html5-mobile-app-running-while-phone-screen-is-off) but it's now 2018. So, how can I still have ECMAScript executed on my phone (to send geolocation position) even if it is asleep? We now have Open Web Apps and Progressive Web Apps (PWA) with service workers, even Apple is jumping in, I'm sure there are ways to do that.

Comment: Why would you want to sniff on my location even though I am not currently using your site? If there is a legitimate use case for this, then you should describe what that is.

Comment: The exact same than described in the original question: tracking the position for example when running. Concerning my specific use case, I'm working for a car pooling company, so it's about knowing the position of the driver to tell the passenger how far he is. Think about it like an native app, except I want to do it in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

While we can hope that things should've changed on this, unfortunately, it has not.

This [article from Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/native-hardware/user-location/) on PWA GeoLocatoin API dated Jan-2018 says clearly that this API works "only while the page is open".

**Why not available yet (in my opinion)?**  Thinking of users privacy, it makes sense. Think of tons of wep pages we visit and for how many we tend to five permission accidentally or we intend to give for a while(until we finish some transaction/booking). Currently there is no way for us to go and check on all location permissions that we've given to web sites in a browser, like we do for Native/Hybrid apps and having option to change it.

We can expect to have tracking option for PWA when it is installed to home screen, where native app like permission handling will be possible to user.

End of the story, we are not there yet!!

**Alternate option:**  While you can use `navigator.geolocation.watchPosition` to track the user when he is actively using the app, You can complement your app with a separately installed (Native) Android service to update the users location to your back end server, till PWA supports naively.