# HTML5 website running geolocation and audio output while phone screen is off?

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome, firefox, geolocation

Very similar questions in the past:

[HTML5 website running while phone screen is off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50150582/html5-website-running-while-phone-screen-is-off)

[HTML5 mobile app running while phone screen is off?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15465242/html5-mobile-app-running-while-phone-screen-is-off)

But now it's 2020... and just a few months ago this worked on firefox. I created a small test page that should "speak" every ~10 seconds and tell you the x/y offset in meters from when you first loaded the page. When the screen is on it also shows you this on a map.

https://supplyrunner.netlify.app/test0/index.html

When the screen was turned off I could not get this working using chrome on my android phone but it worked with firefox. I didn't think the support would get dropped so I didn't note the version of that browser. Now it no longer seems to work with the latest firefox, chrome, or Opera (with the screen off).

1. Is there anything I can do to tell these browsers to continue running in the background? I looked at requesting wakelocks (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/B2G_OS/API/Navigator/requestWakeLock) but that didn't work on firefox and had no effect on chrome.
2. Is there another browser I can use that has more reasonable behavior or options? I believe a user should have the option to run webapps in the background, even if it means explicitly running the browser in a different *mode* (similar to incognito) for the sake of security and transparency.
3. Is there anything I can do in my JS code (web workers?) to force some code to run in the background? Can this code access geolocation and the speech API (so it can talk to the user).
4. Worse case option: Are there any apps I can run that would *simulate* a screen lock such that a user could run the webpage, then run this app *instead* of locking their screen, allowing the page to continue running while the screen turns black and becomes unresponsive to touch (so they can put the phone in their pocket), but the OS doesn't register this as a "screen off" event?
5. Are there any other alternatives that I haven't thought of?

Note that I have an application that requires background geolocation and access to audio out (to speak or play sounds). This was originally written as a native android app but in the past year I have refactored it to be a webapp to avoid issues with google API keys and licenses, to make it OS agnostic (iOS and android), and also to make it much simpler to extend and customize. Going back to a native app is not an option.

Edit:
Here is a simpler page that shows the same issue (with no map) in less than 50 lines of JS/html combined: https://supplyrunner.netlify.app/test1/index.html

I noticed that firefox on android actually still allows some things, like youtube videos, to keep running media in the background with the screen off, but seems to no longer run JS so window.speechSynthesis.speak() and navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() don't work.

Comment: hi...any chance you have had any luck figuring out a workaround for this issue? I too am developing a web app that needs background location and audio output and am stuck. I fear we are out of luck officially, but perhaps there is a clever workaround like your idea of simulating a turned off screen...?

Comment: @hburgund no, sorry... I actually gave up on the idea because I couldn't get anywhere with it. Still hoping that eventually mobile browser implementations will get their act together and provide some reasonable options for what we, and probably many others, are trying to do.

Comment: bummer...thank you for the update though. I'm not going to hold my breath, but yes, maybe some day browsers will allow for more of this sort of native functionality...