# How to keep a web application run in foreground and stop screen turn off and lock in mobile device?

Tags: angular, web-applications

I build an angular web application and deploy it into firebase. I hope the web application can continue run in foreground and stop the screen turn off and lock in the mobile device as long as the app is opened in foreground. Is it possible ?

Does Propgressive web applicationWA can do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can mobile web apps run in the background? (iOS & Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369034/can-mobile-web-apps-run-in-the-background-ios-android)

Comment: @GabrielDevillers, thanks for link to similar question. Since that question is quite old, I wonder if the recent released browsers have new features supporting running web app in background.